# store value of for loop iteration into single variable (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, tkinter

I am trying to save the value of a for loop into a single variable so I can use that variable's string for a tkinter message widget.

Currently every time I return the value of the for loop. It only gives out the 1 iteration.

```
for i in range(len(ticket_json)):
    ticketsubject_str = json.dumps(ticket_json[i]['subject'], indent=2,)
    ticketstatus_str = json.dumps(ticket_json[i]['status'], indent=2,)
    ticketcreationdate = json.dumps(ticket_json[i]['created_at'], indent=2,)
    ticketupdateddate = json.dumps(ticket_json[i]['updated_at'], indent=2)
    ticketstatusreplace_str = ticketstatus_str.replace("2", "Open").replace("5", "Closed")
    words = ticketsubject_str + "\n" + ticketstatusreplace_str + "\n" + ticketcreationdate + "\n" + ticketupdateddate

#button initiators
def myTicketstatusbutton():
    button4 = Message(homepage, justify=LEFT, text = words)
    button4.pack(side=TOP, fill=Y)
```

The result is that the message only shows the last entry in the list.

Is there any way I can save the full value of the for loop as a string variable that I can use? I heard of dictionaries but I am not sure how to convert that loop into a dictionary to test.

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting `words` in the loop.

Set it to the empty string before the loop, then use the `+=` operator to concatenate to the variable rather than overwriting the previous values.

```
words = ''
for i in range(len(ticket_json)):
  ...
  ticketsubject_str = ...
  ticketstatus_str = ...
  ticketcreationdate = ...
  ticketupdateddate = ...
  ticketstatusreplace_str = ...
  words += (...)
```